# How do I run the GruntJS tests?

Tags: unit-testing, node.js, gruntjs

I just cloned the [gruntjs repository](https://github.com/gruntjs).

How do I actually run the tests for GruntJS?

(I don't mean I want to run my own tests using GruntJS. I mean that I want to run the tests for GruntJS itself.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grunt test` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Grunt eats its own dog food.

```
git clone https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt
cd grunt
grunt test
```

Or, like any grunt repository (because the [package.json](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/master/package.json#L23) is well-formed):

```
cd grunt
npm test
```